# Getting NumberFormatException while calling webservice using KSOAP

Tags: android, android-ksoap2, numberformatexception

I am calling a webservice created in `PHP` using this code

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("getCustomerInfo",  "getCustomerInfo");
    request.addProperty("user_id", Info.userId);
    request.addProperty("authToken", Info.authToken);
    request.addProperty("request_id", Integer.toString(CUSTOMERACCOUNTINFO));

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(soapURL);
        httpTransport.debug=true;
        try {               
            httpTransport.call(soap, envelope); //Throwing Exception here
            System.out.println("dump state "+httpTransport.responseDump);
            client.success((Object) envelope.getResponse());
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" exception  num format");
            //client.error("NumberFormatException");
            client.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }catch(XmlPullParserException xppe){
            System.out.println(" exception  pullparser");
            //client.error("XmlPullParserException");
            client.error(xppe.getLocalizedMessage());
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(" exception  io"+ ioe.toString());
            //client.error("IOException");
            client.error(ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

and getting the following error

```
12-31 10:52:03.024: W/System.err(2306): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
12-31 10:52:03.074: W/System.err(2306):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
12-31 10:52:03.104: W/System.err(2306):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
12-31 10:52:03.124: W/System.err(2306):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
12-31 10:52:03.134: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.DM.readInstance(DM.java:39)
12-31 10:52:03.145: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:406)
12-31 10:52:03.155: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:364)
12-31 10:52:03.174: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:233)
12-31 10:52:03.184: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:366)
12-31 10:52:03.194: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readVector(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:287)
12-31 10:52:03.214: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:432)
12-31 10:52:03.224: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:364)
12-31 10:52:03.234: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:233)
12-31 10:52:03.254: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:366)
12-31 10:52:03.264: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:121)
12-31 10:52:03.274: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
12-31 10:52:03.284: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
12-31 10:52:03.294: W/System.err(2306):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
12-31 10:52:03.334: W/System.err(2306):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-31 10:52:03.344: W/System.err(2306):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-31 10:52:03.364: W/System.err(2306):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-31 10:52:03.374: W/System.err(2306):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-31 10:52:03.384: W/System.err(2306):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-31 10:52:03.394: W/System.err(2306):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are passing the empty string "" while the called method is expecting a String representation of a number. Or more precisely, the message you are supposed to send must contains a number somewhere, and instead of *something that can be interpreted as a number* you are passing the empty string.

Double check the value of the parameters you put in the `request`. I guess one of them is the empty string causing the exception.

Comment: I have checked the parameters by harcoding the values and got the same error. I think this error is due to empty string value in response. Is there anyway to check empty string value which needs to get converted into int.

Comment: Indeed, the error occurs in the parseResponse(). I suggest you to put a breakpoint in SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance and see which property is falling (take care that this is a recursive method and so debugging is not easy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think in CUSTOMERACCOUNTINFO the value is null...So, make sure to add some value to CUSTOMERACCOUNTINFO and the parse to Integer..

**OR**

make condition like this..

```
if(CUSTOMERACCOUNTINFO.length()>0)
{
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject("getCustomerInfo",  "getCustomerInfo");
   request.addProperty("user_id", Info.userId);
   request.addProperty("authToken", Info.authToken);
   request.addProperty("request_id", Integer.toString(CUSTOMERACCOUNTINFO));
}
```